# Unable to locate elements (protractor Jasva Script) though CSS seems to be correct in dev tool

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, protractor, locate

[![This image shows html code ][1]][1]

my java script code to locate element in protractor is below :

```
 element(by.css("insight-top-bar insight-predefined-charts-container button div")).click();
```

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: the screenshot was not attached

Answer (score 0):

you might want to add some dots to your locator, for the ones that might belong to a class

`element(by.css('.insight-top-bar.insight-predefined-charts-container button div'))`

Comment: thanks for reply - actually this are all my tags hence no . is required , using same CSS - I can check in dev tool that the elements are highlighting ok so I don't know what is wrong

Comment: can you provide us with a html snipped of the element, or what error you're getting?

Comment: I am unable to attache an image of the code , however , it is not related to locator even I am unable to print the url of that page  with below code                                             const url3= await browser.getCurrentUrl();

                console.log(url3);  I can see on browser that I am able to login successfully and my site's landing page is displayed but unable to interact with it in any way